# How would I represent this in a more object oriented way?

Tags: c++, oop, hashtable

```
typedef char STR10[10+1];
typedef char STR20[20+1];

typdef struct Slot
{
    STR10 key;
    STR10 value;
};

const int MAX_SLOTS = 3;
const int MAX_BUCKETS = 30;

typedef struct Bucket
{

        short int count;
        short int overflow;
        Slot slots[MAX_SLOTS]; 
};

typedef Bucket HashTable[MAX_BUCKETS];
```

Mostly I'm just confused with the concept of the last line. I know I can just change the structs to classes and that would be good, but the last line is getting to me. It's basically saying a HashTable is an array of buckets. Is that code good enough or is there a way to represent that in a HashTable class?

```
class HashTable 
{
private:
   Bucket table[MAX_BUCKETS];
}
```

would that represent the same idea? I'm really struggling with getting this started.

Comment: In general you would a dynamic number of buckets, a fixed size is only useful for a very specific number of entries.

Comment: @AndrewDunn: true in general, but what's more worrying is the fixed number of slots per bucket.  Dear user2023585: a better alternative is a displacement list, where you run through a series of offsets from the hashed-to bucket (%ing back into an actual bucket when necessary) until you find an available one.  You could hardcode the displacements (but still risk failure) or use some function to generate a series.  You want to minimise cases where the sum of existing contiguous offsets equals another offset: if that's confusing, maybe just start with prime numbers....

Comment: Basically just use `std::map` or even better, `std::unordered_map` (if C++11 is an option). Otherwise this smells of homework.

Comment: Yeah it is homework, you must have great smell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I could, I may replace char array with [std::string](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string), Slot array with [std::vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector), replace define with enum:

```
enum SlotSize
{
   MaxSlots = 3
};

enum BucketSize
{
    MaxBuckets = 30
};

struct Slot
{
    std::string key;
    std::string value;
};

struct Bucket
{

    int count;
    int overflow;
    std::vector<Slot> slots;
};

class HashTable 
{
private:
   std::vector<Bucket> table;
}
```

Comment: Ah yes vectors, completely forgot about them. I haven't coded in C++ for going on 6 months, been mainly stuck in scripting languages...

Comment: yeah, use C++ string and STL container to make life easier

Comment: so that class declaration is basically the same concept as that typedef in my original post?

Comment: typedef is more C way, C++ doesn't need it for normal class declaration

Comment: billz: +1 but a minor quip - all-uppercase identifiers risk clashing with preprocessor macros.

Comment: @TonyD Thanks for advice, I've updated them to MaxSlots, MaxBuckets